# Calendar for react native

Tags: reactjs, native

I need a calendar where you can slide from month to month horizontally.
Any of you know how to build one from scratch or one already done? 
Thanks.

Comment: you can find various builded libraries of react-native here:https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native  OR https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-checkbox-green?sort=new&page=7

Comment: Or you can use the one made by airbnb https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates.